# Generating Pre-populated Emails and Windows Character Limits

Tags: angular, windows, email, gridfs, character-limit

We have an in-house Angular app where various emails are auto-generated using `mailto:`. The idea is that a user clicks a button and an email is auto-generated with various dynamic fields pre-populated and then opened in the user's default email client. Then all office staff have to do effectively is click "send".

In testing this on my Mac machine, I have no problems with our current implementation. It all works as expected.

However, with Windows it's a different story (and most staff are on Windows machines with Outlook as the default email client). In Windows you have a hard-cap of 200 characters for generated emails. In other words, if the entire email (headers and all) contains fewer than 200 characters, it will work as expected. But if it's more that 200 characters in total, the email won't open at all.

So, I've been tasked with finding a work-around for this. One option is to use gridFS in our backend Node/MongoDB environment to generate a PDF that we can then either provide a link to in the email, or attach to the email directly. This will work, but feels a little clunky and less than ideal as a user experience.

Is this my only option in this kind of situation? Is anyone aware of any other ways to get around this hard cap of character limits in Windows when auto-generating emails? For instance, can our office staff override this email character limit somewhere in their Windows or Outlook configuration? Is that an option?